# Como proteger una página padre y sus sub-páginas con una contraseña en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, contraseña

Necesito tener una pagina padre protegida con contraseña, si dicha página tiene páginas hijo, también deben estar protegidas.
Al ingresar la contraseña en la página padre se deberá habilitar el acceso a todas las páginas hijo.
No quiero que el usuario tenga que ingresar la contraseña cada vez que abra una página hijo.
Esto no es para proteger todo el sitio.
Cámo podría realizar esa funcionalidad en WordPress?  por favor necesito ayuda!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalmente no suelo responder preguntas que no tienen un trabajo de investigación previo, sin embargo esta pregunta si es interesante así que te daré una idea de como hacerlo.

WordPress ya tiene un area para proteger con contraseña pero lo tienes que hacer por pagina así que se me ocurre que en vez de eso lo puedes hacer verificando las cookies.

Primero crea un Field que guardara el password, si no sabes mucho de programación hazlo con Awesome Custom Fields

Luego en el single de tu post llama al field que guarda la contraseña, cambia el key por el que usaste al configurar ACF.

```
$password = get_field( 'password' );
```

Luego puedes crear un formulario donde se tenga que agregar la contraseña, entonces al enviar el formulario si la contraseña es correcta creas una cookie

```
if ( $_POST['submit'] ) {
    if ( $_POST['password'] == $password ) {
        setcookie( "show_page", get_the_ID(), time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
}
```

Esta contraseña se verifica como texto plano, aquí la puedes agregar encriptación en base64 o el método que quieras, todo depende de que tan seguro quieres que sea.

ahora ya tenemos una cookie llamada show_page que guarda el ID de la publicación padre, entonces para los hijos puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['show_page'] ) ) {
    if ( $_COOKIE['show_page'] == $post->post_parent ) {

        // Your Code Here

    }
}
```

Esto verifica si existe la cookie show_page y si el contenido de dicha cookie es igual al ID del post padre de la publicación actual.

Claro, esto requiere mas trabajo pero con eso te puedes dar una idea de que camino tomar, nada de esto lo he probado así que no estoy seguro si funcionara correctamente.

Otra forma seria obtener todos los hijos de la publicación padre y asígnales un post meta que se actualizara a true, estoy seguro de que hay muchas otras formas de hacer esto o simplemente usar algun plugin que haga el trabajo.